# I can't find a way to make Auto Layout constraints happy

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout

I am trying to make this simple layout:

[image]

It's just a simple `UICollectionViewCell`.

But when I put all the auto layout constraints I believe are needed, I get this warning:

```
NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17028dd40 H:[UIImageView:0x13fd3b000(48)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17028e2e0 H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x13fd3bfe0'Something as a title...']   (Names: '|':_UIVisualEffectContentView:0x13fd3ace0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17028e380 UILabel:0x13fd3bfe0'Something as a title...'.leading == UIImageView:0x13fd3b000.leading>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17028e470 H:[UIImageView:0x13fd3b000]-(8)-[UILabel:0x13fd3b140'Lady Oracle']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17028e4c0 H:[UILabel:0x13fd3b140'Firstname Lastname']-(8)-|   (Names: '|':_UIVisualEffectContentView:0x13fd3ace0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17028e830 H:|-(0)-[UIVisualEffectView:0x13fe0ebd0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x13fe142d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17028e8d0 H:[UIVisualEffectView:0x13fe0ebd0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x13fe142d0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x17428ee70 h=-&- v=-&- _UIVisualEffectContentView:0x13fd3ace0.width == UIVisualEffectView:0x13fe0ebd0.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x17028fd20 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x13fe142d0(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17028dd40 H:[UIImageView:0x13fd3b000(48)]>
```

As can be inferred from the log I have the following constraints:

- **bottom container view**: bottom, leading and trailing aligned to super view
- **title**: top, leading and trailing spacing to container view. Bottom spacing to *user avatar*.
- **user avatar**: to have specific size (width & height), horizontal aligned with the title, vertical spacing with the *title*, bottom space to container.
- **user name**: top aligned to *user avatar*, leading spacing to *user avatar*, trailing spacing to container.

I can't seem to have sufficient constraints to make the layout how I want and get rid of the warning. The layout is appearing as expected, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is two thing I can think of:

1. you forgot to set the views with..

   ```
   [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
   ```
2. your collectionView cell size its to small when the collection view is trying to layout.

Comment: I have to set this on all the views?

Comment: Setting this to all of them makes the containerView at the bottom go to the top. And the two lines text becomes one line and it appear to go beyond the size of the container view.

Comment: ok so that mean that something with your constraints is off, I'm at work I will look at it again later and will try to figure out what is off..